# where is the PuPHPet site gone?

Tags: vagrant, magento2, puphpet

There used to be a gui where you could configure PuPHPet settings for vagrant.
It would allow you to set, shared folders, users, Apache, Mysql, etc.

I can't seem to find this site anymore. Is it gone?
Is there an alternative way to configure a vagrant for Magento?

Answer (score 3):

PuPHPet is abadoned according to it's creator: https://twitter.com/juantreminio/status/1199022035588075520

However, the whole project was open source and you can find the repositories here:
https://github.com/puphpet